# C# 7.0 in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c#-7.0

Can you switch on C# 7.0 features within Visual Studio 2015 (Enterprise) or do you need to upgrade to 2017?

Comment: If you have Enterprise, you have an MSDN subscription as well. VS 2017 RTMs in a couple of weeks. It already has a Go-Live license

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yeah just seen that as we speak thank you :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can replace the compiler shipped with Visual Studio for a C# 7-enabled version by installing the Nuget package [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/):

> Referencing this package will cause the project to be built using the
>   specific version of the C# and Visual Basic compilers contained in the
>   package, as opposed to any system installed version.

There is no indication that I can see on the package page as to whether this is officially supported in Visual Studio 2015. My not-thorough tests so far indicate that it works but not painlessly - C# 7 code compiles, but is underlined with the red squiggly line which indicates a syntax error:

[image: Screenshot] Note that you will also need to install the Nuget package [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) to use the new C# 7 value tuples features.

Comment: Notice there is still an error (red squiggly line) in the editor window. Having VS still reporting errors even though the Build succeeded is not a great solution. Anyone know how to get the VS editor to stop showing these false-positive errors?

Answer (score 3):

You have to download/checkout and build the NET Compiler Platform ("**Roslyn**") from **Github** and then you can test the C# 7 Features with VS 2015!

More Info:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master

*If you like video tutorials, than watch this video:*

https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/lrn-quick-tip-how-to-test-out-c-7-features-with-roslyn/

Comment: Do not down vote without to leave a comment, you have to exmplain why you did that. Be a brave and a good man and remove it! my answer is more correct then the selected one!

Comment: Hi @BassamAlugili, is it possible what you are saying for VS 2015 professional?

Comment: I didn't understand why people are down voting @BassamAlugili answer.

Comment: @BassamAlugili has given his opinion and it is correct.   

Everybody knows that C# 7 support has been provided wit Visual Studio 2017.  

But it is also possible with Visual Studio 2015 update 2 by using Roslyn Latest source code. 

Below is a small link how to test C# 7 feature with Visual Studio 2015.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-compile-test-C-Sharp-7-features/

But it requires a lot of setting changes so I will recommend using Visual Studio 2017 RC in wich use can test your C# 7 features in one go.

Comment: But if you would not like to play with Compiler source code I will always recommend to use Visual Studio 2017.  link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/top-10-new-features-of-c-sharp-7-with-visual-studio-2017/ have the list of supported C#7 features with Visual Studio 2017.